# Javascript that automatically sets font-size on element so that text doesn't overflow? (autofit)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

You know what I mean?
Like let's say we have:

```
<div style="width:100px;font-size:10px">Some Text</div>
```

But then we could also possibly have a much longer text string in that div, in that case I would want that div to have font-size:7px or whatever, so that the whole string fits without overflowing.

I'm sure there's already something like this written, I wouldn't want to reinvent this. Preferably a jQuery plugin?

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: This question is very similar to a one [asked earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177320/programmatically-determine-font-size-for-single-line-display/1177753#1177753).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on an answer proposed in Nick's question:

```
$(function() {
    $(".shrinkByWidth").each(function() {
        var targetWidth = $(this).parent(':first').width();

        if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).css("font-size"))))
            $(this).css("font-size", '24px');

        while ($(this).width() > targetWidth) 
        {
            $(this).css("font-size", (parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) - 1) + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

Works great for me!