# How can I calculate how many characters will fit on the screen? 

Tags: javascript, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I measure how many characters will fit the width of the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875183/how-can-i-measure-how-many-characters-will-fit-the-width-of-the-document)

I'm developing a mobile website and I've run into a problem.  The site gets the mobile device's screen size and needs to calculate how many characters it can fit on the screen. Once this information is known, a string of that length will be pulled from the server using AJAX.

The problem is, I am not sure how I can perform this calculation using JavaScript.  Does anybody know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the problem is "How can i calculate characters(symbols) length with JavaScript on the assumption of mobile device screen size?"

Unless you use a [fixed-width font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), you can't. Not without knowing the text's contents in advance. That's because in every normal font, every character (and sometimes, even every character pair) has a different width.

Maybe elaborate some more about your requirement. I'm fairly sure there is a much simpler solution for what you need to do.

Comment: Once you leave English, I believe it can get even worse than every character pair, by the way...

Comment: i use the following fonts "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif and font-size is 16px.

Comment: @Miro those aren't fixed-width fonts, so you can't do this.

Comment: i saw simpler application which can calculate screen size and get text  from server. here is http://www.onread.com/fbreader/1465808.

Comment: @Miro what do you need this for in the first place? This sounds like a completely unnecessary requirement. What is your actual issue?

Comment: i figured out how can calculate. needs to get div which have another div inside and set text inner div. Then check the height of inner div with parent div. :) thanks Pekka.